# Old C128 - normal to straight away pull 2 amps?

Tags: commodore, commodore-128

I'm trying to get an old C128 working again. Lacking a C128 power supply, I've attached a C64's power supply's 9VAC and am supplying 5VDC from a bench power supply (with a 2A limit at the moment).

There's an old CRT TV attached to the Composite output and an old Commodore 1404 screen (which might or might not be working) is attached to the DB9 socket.

Switching the C128 on immediately draws 2A. Neither screen shows any kind of output. As far as I can tell with a quick check, the only IC that gets warm (but not hot) is the 7812. There are no funny noises or smells.

My question at this point is mainly whether it might make sense to try with a 3 amps limit?

(In case anyone happens to be hanging around 35C3, I'm at doubleoctothorpbuero (just type "double" in the C3Nav and it'll autocomplete). Thankful for any hints or pointers! :-))

Edit: thank you for the comments. I've added a question that should make it clear what I'm asking. But please keep it on hold for now as I'm trying to follow @'Brian H''s suggestion of finding a known-good device to test monitor and power supply with. Given that there's a PDP11 standing down the hall, there should also be plenty of at least C64 around here.

Comment: I'm not certain what your question here is. Please read the [tour], then [edit] your question to be clearer.

Comment: The question is quite obvious, it's in the subject.

Comment: This http://www.hardwarebook.info/C128_Power_Supply says 5V at 2.5A. If you are limiting to 2A and are at that limit, the voltage will be less than 5V so nothing is likely to work. Try increasing the limit to 3A. If you are still current limited, you need to find out why before you do anything else.

Comment: A known-working C64 or C128 would come in very handy here, as you are working with several independent variables. I'd want to confirm my Power Supply rig and video displays were good-to-go before going any farther.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the 5V of the C64 brick (Pin5)? I'd just hook it up. A look at the service manuals (with schematics) might be helpful as well - http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/schematics/computers/c128/servicemanuals/index.html

Comment: @alephzero: Didn't find a known-working C64 yet. Did try with 3A, and the voltage still drops to around 3.75V. Really, really curious.

Comment: @Raffzahn: that's what I started out with, but the voltage dropped to around 2.5V with the C64 PSU's 5V.

Comment: Commodore C128 compatible Stabilized 5VDC **up to 3.0A output** [here](https://www.c64psu.com/c64psu/48-171-commodore-c128-128-psu-power-supply-unit.html)

Comment: @Michael, thanks so much for that link! As far as the Congress is concerned, there's now a "Please fix me" sticker on the C128 and I'm hoping for someone to come by and try to help. More likely I'll wait until I find some time back home to fix it.